# Why there is no @FeignClient annotation in feign client template in OpenApi

Tags: openapi, spring-cloud-feign, openapi-generator, openfeign

Straight to the point -> anybody knows why this [template file](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/libraries/feign/api.mustache) does not have @FeignClient annotation?

Problem is we would like to use @EnableFeignClients annotation in our configuration, but seems like without @FeignClient anootations in generated clients we are forced to create client beans explicitly.